# How to check of the last 2 entries of a mysql query in various column have the same value?

Tags: php, mysql

i have a table  link with a structure like this

```
spreader | host1 | host2 | host 3 | id | datetime |
---------------------------------
expl.com | 1     | 5     | 2
what.de  | 1     | 5     | 2
expl.com | 1     | 2     | 3
what.de  | 2     | 5     | 5
```

How to check if the last 2 entry with the same spreader have the same values in host1, host2, host3 ...

For this example it sould give me

> - expl.com => host1 = 1
> - what.de => host2 = 5

I maybe know a way but i would have to have 10 sql querys one for each host. Do you know a efficient way to do this in php after i just get the entire date from the database with just one query?

Well i got this now it fires out 10 mysql querys i would love to see how to make this better:

```
global $hosters;
global $filespreader_names;

foreach ( $filespreader_names as $filespreader ) {
    $feedtable = feedback_tabelle_holen(" WHERE filespreader='$filespreader' ORDER BY aktualisiert DESC LIMIT 2");
    //var_dump($feedtable);
    foreach ( $hosters as $host ) {
        if ( ( $feedtable[0][$host] == $feedtable[1][$host] ) && ( $feedtable[0][$host] != 0 ) ) {
            echo "<br />$filespreader -> $host = " . $feedtable[0][$host];
        }
    }
}
```

the globals i get in are just arrays with all the spreaders and host names i need

Comment: can you display the structure of your tables like table name and its columns in format?

Comment: I am sorry but could you be more specific. may be an example can help

Comment: What do you mean with "last two entry"? How do you know they are the last? Do you have some date-time field or some auto-increment column? Remember that when you query a db nothing assures you that you get records in the exact order they have been stored...

Comment: i have id and datetime. thats not he problem. i just want to get check if the last 2 raws of a "spreader" (of whatevery query i run) have something in common and then print out what.

Comment: I think you need a more detailed example.

Comment: And do you mean the last 2 by datetime? Or last 2 by id? or last 2 by the random order they are outputed each time?

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do an Inner Join to produce matching records. If the gloabals you get in are from another table an inner join will give you a recordset with all the matching records that you could manipulate from there but it would only be one query.

```
If this is TableA on the left and TableB on the right.

id name       id  name
-- ----       --  ----
1  Pirate     1   Rutabaga
2  Monkey     2   Pirate
3  Ninja      3   Darth Vader
4  Spaghetti  4   Ninja

SELECT * FROM TableA
INNER JOIN TableB
ON TableA.name = TableB.name

That query will result in rows of the  matching data according to your query

id  name       id   name
--  ----       --   ----
1   Pirate     2    Pirate
3   Ninja      4    Ninja
```

I don't know if that helps at all but I wasn't really clear on your structure and exactly what you wanted. If the globals are session variables and not stored in a table this answer probably won't help you.

If you want to use joins check out http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html